# How can i get Content Type from SharePoint site 2010 using SharePoint Manager 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

i have a Publish SharePoint Site 2010, I will import the all Content Type from it Using SharePoint Manager 2010

please any solution about how do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

i would just save the site as a site template from site settings;
Then open the site into Visualstudio you can then just select just the content types
Which would then give you a perfect package which could be deployed

Comment: I have a Publishing Site Therefore i can't save't as "site template" !?

Comment: You will actuall still be able to save the site as a template to extract the content type. a) go into sharepoint designer, the option is still there on publishing types. b) just go straight to the url in the ui i believe its /layouts/savetmp.aspx. it will still work. Word of advance I would only extract only the custom content types out of this site template and create a new package. As it will not work deploying it back with all the workflow assoicated with pubishing sites

Comment: i tried to do that but when i open the SharePoint designer, the button:"save as template" stay unavailable, so please any assistance

Answer (score 0):

Try this url //[localhost]/_layouts/savetmpl.aspx, you may need to replace localhost with your server or domain name.
On other note you can use [SharePoint site explorer or Sharepoint insider 2010/2013](http://www.aurorabits.com). Their tools can be installed on the server or run from a desktop without requiring to login to the server.